# Cross-Domain Magic: iFrames, JavaScript, or both?

Tags: javascript

The long and short is this:

I'm creating an embeddable widget that developers can embed on their site. I need to run some JavaScript on these external sites, but I also need to make GET and POST requests to my own server. Additionally, I need to know if a visitor using this widget is authenticated with my application.

I can't quite decide how to go about this in a secure way. iFrames would be ideal if I didn't need to run javascript and pass data to/from the page that is hosting my widget. I don't think I can allow JavaScript to access the contents of my iFrame without exposing myself to malicious code.

Is there a common practice to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I'm running a Node/Express server on my backend, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Learn about `window.postMessage`

Comment: I've read about this - but couldn't a malicious actor use this to send unauthorized requests?

Comment: @opticon The event object for the received message has an `origin` field indicating what origin sent the message, which you can use to filter out unauthorized senders. See [MDN's page on `postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage), in particular the second paragraph of the ["*Security concerns*" section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#Security_concerns).

Answer (score 1):

Two technologies you can use to enable this:

1. Cross Origin Resource Sharing

   Since the widgets will be running on your customers' sites, and you want to gate-keep that, this is exactly what [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) is for.

   You write your site's code to only support cross-origin requests from whitelisted sites, and you keep that list up to date as you add customers for the widget. Anyone trying to use the widget from an unauthorized site will run into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (because your site won't enable access for them via CORS), and the request will fail.

   If you need to support your customers' users using IE8 or IE9, you'll need to write the widget to deal with that fact that IE8-9's handling of CORS [is broken](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors); you have to use the IE-only `XDomainRequest` rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. (And if you use jQuery, no, this is a cross-browser issue they decided not to handle for you.) IE10 and up fix this problem.
2. `postMessage`

   As [epascarello points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050668/cross-domain-magic-iframes-javascript-or-both/28050747#comment44483449_28050668), for the purely client-side cross-origin communication (e.g., if you wanted to use iframes), you can use `postMessage`, which enables secure cross-origin messaging even without CORS, because code on each side of the message has to opt-in to the message. To ensure you only deal with messages you trust, look at the `origin` property of the message event (any decent article you find on `postMessage` will show how that works), and be sure that the code can't be copied and trivially hacked to work when served not from your origin (e.g., ensure that somewhere, somehow, you're using the SOP to protect it).

It'll be an either-or thing, most likely: CORS if you want the widget to be embedded in the other site's HTML (which is what I'd likely do), `postMessage` and *not* CORS if you're going to use iframes (I'm assuming there will be communication with the server).